# Why isn't Entity automatically completing the relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three models: `Document`, `Section`, and `Paragraph`.  Each one looks like this.

```
// Document
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

// Section
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

// Paragraph
public class Paragraph
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

Entity is automatically populating `Section.Paragraphs` with all the paragraphs where `SectionId == Id`.  This is not happening though for `Document.Sections`.  Instead of `Document.Sections` being populated with all sections where `DocumentId == id`, `Document.Sections` is null.  Argh!

Comment: Are these relationships defined in the database?

Comment: They should be automatically defined by Entity.

Comment: @dunsmoreb if you are using db first and  they are not defined in your db as foreign keys EF will most likely will not define them

Comment: Well the interesting thing is that Section -> Paragraph works but not Document -> Section.

Comment: Relationships are straight forward so EF should be able to map them correctly. Do you have manually entered data that has inconsistencies that prevent EF from materializing entities?

Comment: The data should be find as everything was fine earlier today and I have not changed the data being populated (it is automatically populated via an initializer.)

Comment: Do you use proxies for the fixup of relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following annotations:

```
// Document
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Document")]
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

// Section
public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Document")]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Section")]
    public virtual ICollection<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

// Paragraph
public class Paragraph
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }


    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

I'm gonna assume this as well:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Document> Documents {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Paragraph> Paragraphs {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Section> Sections {get;set;}
}
```

Tell me if it helped you in any way. There could be issue with how you load entities (do you use Include).

Comment: This works, but why does `Section -> Paragraphs` works without this fix?

Comment: It's not a fix. This is the way how you map navigational ends. EF will try to figure out it on it's own as best as it can and it tends to fail. If you specify navigational ends with InverseProperty (setting it on only 1 side should suffice), then it won't miss. Is it clear for you how is this set?